# Invalid opcode when trying to pass address as parameter to contract

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, solidity-0.5.x

When I try to pass address as parameter to this addEmployee function it gives me this **error**:

```
invalid opcode
    The execution might have thrown.
    Debug to get more information.
```

```
modifier onlyOwner()
{
    require(msg.sender==owner,"msg.sender is not the Owner");
    _;
}

function addEmployee(address payable employeeWallet) onlyOwner external
{
    emp[emp.length-1] = employeeWallet;
}
```

Comment: An Invalid Opcode exception is the result of either one of two things: 1. An `assert(cond)` statement, where `cond` evaluates to `false`. 2. An `array[n]` statement, where `n` exceeds the boundaries of the array (i.e., `n < 0 || n >= array.length`). So when you get this type of exception, always look for either one of those two "things" in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This is just an educated guess, to be 100% certain I'd need to see your entire contract and the series of calls leading up to the error)*

An `INVALID` opcode is raised when you attempt to access a storage location that hasn't been intialized. In this case, you are attempting to store data in a dynamic array `emp` at location `emp.length-1`. Because the length of `emp` is zero, the calculation `emp.length-1` underflows and the EVM reverts when it cannot access `emp[2^256-1]`.

As an alternative, I suggest using `emp.push(employeeWallet)` for appending the new value to the array.

Useful reading:

- Solidity documentation: [Arrays](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/types.html#arrays)
- Blockgeeks: [Overflow and Underflow Errors](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/underflow-attacks-smart-contracts/)